# CSS position a button inside gridview cell (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, gridview

I've been struggling to position the edit button inside a gridview cell in the top right corner of the cell. The row height varies from row to row so I cannot use CSS height and the inside div does not fill the whole height of the row.
Basically I want all the divs inside the template field (td) be the same height as the whole table row (tr).
I attached two pics of what I get and what I want. Can someone help?

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Префикс GS1" SortExpression="gs1prefix">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div style="width:110px;">
            <div style="top:0;right:0">
                <div style="font-size:0.6em;">
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkEdit2" CommandName="Edit" Text="(Изменить)" />
                </div>
            </div>
           <asp:Label runat="server" Font-Bold="true" ID="lblPartnersGs1Prefix" Text='<%# Eval("gs1prefix") %>' />
       </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField
```

What I get:

[image: What I get]

What I want to get:

[image: What I want to get]

**UPDATE:**
Here's generated HTML:

```
<td align="center" valign="middle">
    <div style="width:110px;">
        <div style="top:0;right:0">
            <div style="font-size:0.6em;">
                <a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_gvPartners_lnkEdit2_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvPartners$ctl02$lnkEdit2','')">(Изменить)</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_gvPartners_lblPartnersGs1Prefix_0" style="font-weight:bold;">501028410</span>
    </div>
</td>
```

And the stylesheet fragment:

```
.ColoredGridView{
    background-color:white;
}

.ColoredGridView td {
    background-color: #9deef1;
    border-style: none;
    border-width: 0;
    padding: 8px;
}

.ColoredGridView td a
{
    border-bottom: 1px dotted;
    text-decoration-line:none;
}
```

Comment: Open inspect, copy the that html section your code is generating and post it here. Increases a lot the chances for a good and fast answer.

Comment: Even better, [create a plunkr.](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that you could tackle this

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" cssClass="myClass" ID="lnkEdit2" CommandName="Edit" Text="(Изменить)" />
```

and in your CSS create a class and then position it how you need

or

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" style="text-align: right; vertical-align: top;" ID="lnkEdit2" CommandName="Edit" Text="(Изменить)" />
```

Comment: I want the button to be at the top right corner, not in the middle